# Correct usage of "to" + verb

Tags: word-usage

I have an interface which limits users' access. I want to write a phrase that expresses it differently.

Here is what I come up with

> The interface offers the option to pick which ones* to authorize
>   client access.

ones refers to clients. I feel that the sentence is not right, as I'm not sure if the usage of "to authorize" is correct.

Looking for feedback on this; different formulation are certainly welcome!

Comment: I would say something like, "The interface gives clients options that determine their user access." or "The interface allows clients to choose an option that determines their level of access." or "The interface tailors the user access based on the option the client chooses."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title you give to your question seems to indicate that you are confusing the two roles of *to*:

the **infinitive marker**

a **preposition** (often used in idioms where it is not easily definable semantically)

Making your sentence a little less complicated, to illustrate:

**We want / need to allow client access to certain documents.**

*Want* and *need*, as is the case with some other similar verbs, may be used in catenative constructions with other verbs:

I want to go.
He needs to ask.
He seems to think so.

These verbs require the 'to-infinitive' rather than the 'bare infinitive', the base form of the verb (actually, *need* can be used with the base form in some situations).

*Help* and *dare* may be used in **some** situations with either the to-infinitive or the bare infinitive:

he didn't dare to go / he didn't dare go

she helped to wash up / she helped wash up

dare you go? /*dare you to go?

In your sentence, *to authorize* is a to-infinitive, as is my *to allow*.

However, my sentence also contains *access to certain documents*, where *to* is a preposition. It forms a collocation with *access* (we always would say *access to* rather than *access for*, or *access over*, the documents).

Omitting the preposition *to* from my sentence leaves:

** *We want / need to allow client access certain documents.** (*access* of course is still a noun here) It is obvious in this example that the preposition *to* is required; this is also true for your example, though inserting it at the end of the sentence results in a correct but clumsy-sounding sentence:

The interface offers the option to pick which ones to authorize client access to.

Comment: You authorize access *for* somebody and *to* something. So "... which ones to authorize client access for," which is unfortunately a rather unwieldy sentence.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot missing from your context:

1. Who does the interface offer the option to?
2. By "*users*" do you also mean "*clients*?"

---

> The interface offers the option to pick which ones to authorize client
>   access.

Let's make it simple by substituting the word "clients" in your sentence:

> The interface offers the option to pick which *clients* to authorize client
>   access.

If I understand your situation correctly, there's a redundancy in your sentence that needs to be removed. This way:

- The interface offers the option to pick which *clients* **to authorize**.
- The interface offers the option to pick which *clients* **to give access 
  to**.

It would depend a lot on your context, but you should keep in mind that the word "*client*" must be the object that receives the action of whatever verb you put inside the infinitive.